# Why do Blast Furnace flue dust generates high rates of Zn (Zinc)?

Tags: chemical-engineering, metallurgy, chemistry

The Blast Furnace flue dust contains high rates of Zn (Zinc). I'd like to know the reason behind this. The chemical reaction of Zn inside blast furnace dust. Why it's rates becoming high?

Comment: Is it in the raw material? Does the raw material composition vary?

Comment: Yes raw material, there are other materials in it. Cl, mineral oils are high levels as well as Zn. Composition contains many heavy metals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not likely unless they use a very unusual ore. Blast furnaces generally do not use scrap. Scrap likely contains zinc ( die castings) . Electric arc remelt furnaces melt a high percentage of recycle containing zinc. There may still be open hearths or other furnaces used to melt recycle. So, furnaces other than blast furnaces are likely the source. Depending on the system , dust from different types of furnaces may be collected in one facility which may not be differentiated , leading to the idea that zinc is coming from a blast furnace.  Generally the mills remove as much zinc as possible from the recycle as I understand it causes deterioration of the refractories. After it is a few hours old ,zinc oxide is innocuous and is used in skin creams.

Comment: So what chemical composition is ideal for ore to be usual? And what kind of characteristics that unusual ore may have so that causes high Zinc..?

Comment: I think we are talking about different kinds of furnaces. What is the raw material input and what is the energy source of your furnace ?